# django - how to make newline in many if-clauses

Tags: django, django-templates

I am wondering how I can make newline if I have many if-clauses like this:

```
{% if request.path != "/a/" and request.path != "/b/" and request.path != "/c/" ...many more %}

{% endif %}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
{% if request.path != "/a/" 
   and request.path != "/b/" 
   and request.path != "/c/" 
   ...many more %}

{% endif %}
```

or something shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you put the list of paths into the context:

```
return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', {'paths': ['/a/', '/b/', '/c/']})
```

And use built-in [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator) in the template:

```
{% if request.path in paths %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```